# iphone app crashes on first startup

Tags: iphone, crash, startup

Just wondering why my newly made application crashes the first time I run it on my iPod but works every single time after that. I have been developing completely with storyboards, and so far I have no written any code. Could anyone please tell me how the fix the crash when I open my app for the first time?

Comment: Are you connecting your device with Mac and running the app in Xcode? There should be some additional error information printed in the Xcode debugger console. That will be helpful to spot the root cause.

Comment: Two questions: 1) When you run it the first time, are you doing so through XCode? 2) When you run it "every single time after that", are you again running through XCode or are you now tapping icon on device?

Comment: your app may not exist completely after the first time. You should kill the app from background.

Comment: I am running it from Xcode. It only crashes the first time, and even if i close the app from the multitask bar it will never crash again. Im just more sure what the problem is... Also, how do breakpoints help me here?

Comment: On, xcode, no bug report shows up, or do I have to manually open the crash reports?

Comment: mine crash on first compiled. Then can run it afterwards without any problem. What is happening?

Answer (score 1):

If you are running your app in Xcode (connecting your device), you may add break point from Xcode. On the left panel, click on break point toolbar, press "+" to add Exception Breakpoint...

This will stop the in your app's code, at least you should have some controller codes related to your your storyboard views.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner, but I don't understand how break points will help me here.

Comment: You want the program to stop as early as it has noticed a problem, and have it report what problem/exception it has encountered. Otherwise, the underlying cause could be buried under subsequent, unrelated issues (very likely in your case, since we're not seeing a meaningful error on console).